# Filter for timestamp with maximum number of records for each date and extract the filtered rows into another df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a timestamp column, another date column and price column.
The timestamp column is more like every 5 min data for a specific hour (between 10 am and 11 am) that am pulling out.
Eg:

```
Timestamp               EndDate             Price  
2021-01-01 10:00:00   2021-06-30 08:00:00    100
2021-01-01 10:00:00   2021-09-30 08:00:00    105
2021-01-01 10:05:00   2021-03-30 08:00:00    102
2021-01-01 10:05:00   2021-06-30 08:00:00    100
2021-01-01 10:05:00   2021-09-30 08:00:00    105
2021-01-01 10:10:00   2021-03-30 08:00:00    102
2021-01-01 10:10:00   2021-06-30 08:00:00    100

2021-01-02 10:00:00   2021-06-30 08:00:00    100
2021-01-02 10:00:00   2021-09-30 08:00:00    105
2021-01-02 10:00:00   2021-03-30 08:00:00    102
2021-01-02 10:00:00   2021-06-30 08:00:00    100
2021-01-02 10:05:00   2021-09-30 08:00:00    105
2021-01-02 10:05:00   2021-03-30 08:00:00    102
2021-01-02 10:05:00   2021-06-30 08:00:00    100
```

For the snapshot every 5 min, some end up with 3 records, some with 2, some with 4 records.
Within that hour (or day)  I want to pull out the set of records such that the set contains the maximum number of records, so for the 1st of jan in the above example, it should pull out 10:05 data, for 2nd jan it should pull out 10:00 data. If there are multiple sets with the same number of max records, then it can pull out the latest time for that day.

Am not sure how I can do this efficiently, perhaps use a count ?

Comment: Sounds like you need a windowing function. You may need to create two columns, one for day and another for hour and partition over those hours. In Pandas, you would do a `.groupby` over those columns and then use the `transform` method.

Answer (score 0):

u can split the the timstap for a better use, so i did this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename=(r'C:xxxxxx\Example2.xlsx') 
df0=pd.read_excel(filename)
df0['new_date'] = [d.date() for d in df0['Timestamp']]
df0['new_time'] = [d.time() for d in df0['Timestamp']]
```

this yields:
[image]

then we can use groupby() and thn apply() to count values as follow:

```
df = df0.groupby('new_date')['new_time'].apply(lambda x: 
x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()
```

that yields:
[image]